# Creating a carousel effect with jquery - Loop returning only the last value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a carousel effect, but my loop is only returning the last value inside the array. I would like to iterate through each item after a specific time. Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/intercoder/pen/118bc6426e332eec41b4589022c99c36) with the code.

```js
$(function() {
  //var timer = 3000;

  var $items = $('img', '.container');
  var currentIdx = 0;

  var cycleItems = function() {
    console.log('Running from cycleItems');
    var item = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) {
      var item = $items[i];

      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('We are at this item: ${item}');
        console.log('And we are at this index: ' + currentIdx);

        if ($(item).hasClass('isHidden')) {
          $(item).removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive')
        }
        currentIdx++
      }, 3000);
    }
  }


  /*$item.removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive).setTimeout(function() { $( this ).animate( { scrollLeft: 200 + 'px' } ), '500', 'swing', function() { console.log('Animation completed') } }) */
  cycleItems();
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  background: black;
}
.container {
  display: inline;
  //border: 1px solid white;

}
.slide {} .isActive {
  visibility: visible;
}
.isHidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
  <img class='isActive' src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img class='isHidden' src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img class='isHidden' src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img class='isHidden' src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't edit SOLVED into the title: [Is it OK to add Solved to the title of a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/194720)

Comment: @Mike McCaughan Ooops sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function() {
//var timer = 3000;

var $items = $('img','.container');
var currentIdx = 0;

var cycleItems = function() {
console.log('Running from cycleItems');

  $items.each(function(index, item){
    setTimeout(function() {

      console.log(`We are at this item: ${index}`);
      console.log('And we are at this index: ' + currentIdx );
      $(item).removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive') 
      /*if ( $(item).hasClass('isHidden') ) {

       } */
      currentIdx++
     }, 3000*index);
 });
}

     /*$item.removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive).setTimeout(function()   { $( this ).animate( { scrollLeft: 200 + 'px' } ), '500', 'swing',     function() { console.log('Animation completed') } }) */
cycleItems();
});
```

it's important to multiply the timer with the index otherwise you'll get your timer working only once.

Comment: glad I cloud help! Cheers ;-)